# How do I add an array of records at the beginning of another array of records?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays

I have two arrays of database records.

I'd like to add the second one to the beginning of the first.

I looked into `insert`, at a specific indexx, but it would result in inserting the second array inside the first one.

It might not be that hard, but thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: example please with expected output and input

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How is this [`Array#+`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-i-2B) ?

```
array2 = [1,2,3]
array1 = [11,21]

array2 + array1
# => [1, 2, 3, 11, 21]
```

Comment: well… I'm quite ashamed as it is pretty obvious, it is just an order thing. I guess I have to get some rest… thanks a lot !

Comment: *Nice sense of humour* :))

Answer (score 3):

Ruby's splat to the rescue:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [4, 5, 6]

a.unshift(*b)
a #=> [4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3]
```